# Local DHCP to setting up Nimbus cloud networking

Tags: networking, centos, linux-networking, cloud

I'm currently trying to install the Nimbus cloud in two machines (centOS 6) test environment inside the department/university network. The problem is that I can't install directly a DHCP server and I'm struggling to find a solution to create a local DHCP server. The host machine where I will need to install a VMM has a static IP. I'm not an expert in networking and every suggestion will be really appreciated.

Comment: It is really necessary to ensure that your local sysadmin is aware of what you are doing.

Comment: You can cause some serious problems installing a DHCP server incorrectly on a VM within an existing network. Ask your local sysadmin for advice first!